# Regex search overlapping matches c++11

Tags: regex, c++11

What regex expression should I use to search all occurrences that match:

- Start with 55 or 66
- followed by a minimum 8 characters in the range of `[0-9a-fA-F]` (HEX numbers)
- Ends with `\r` *(a carriage return)*

**Example string**: 0205065509085503400066/r09\r

My expected result:

```
5509085503400066\r
5503400066\r
```

My current result:

```
5509085503400066\r
```

Using

```
 (?:55|66)[0-9a-fA-F]{8,}\r
```

As you can sie, this finds onlny the first result but not the second one.

**Edit clarification**

I search the string using Regex. It'll select the message for further parsing. The target string can start anywhere in the string. The target string is only valid if it only contains base-16 (HEX) numbers, and ends with a carriage return.

**[start] [information part minimum 8 chars] [end symbol-carigge return]**

I'm using the std::regex library in c++11 with the flag **ECMAScript**

**Edit**

I have created an alternative solution that gives me the expected result. But this is not pure regex.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
int main()
{
// repeated search (see also 
std::regex_iterator)
std::string log("0055\r0655036608090705\r");
std::regex r("(?:55|66)[0-9a-fA-F]{8,}\r");
std::smatch sm;
while(regex_search(log, sm, r))
{
    std::cout << sm.str() << '\n';
    log = sm.str();
    log += sm.suffix();
    log[0] = 'a' ;
}
}
```

** Edit: Working regex solution based on comments **

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
// repeated search (see also 
std::regex_iterator)
std::string s("0055\r06550003665508090705\r0970");
std::regex r("(?=((?:55|66)[0-9a-fA-F]{8,}\r))");
auto words_begin = 
    std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
auto words_end =  std::sregex_iterator();

std::cout << "Found " 
          << std::distance(words_begin, words_end) 
          << " words:\n";

for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
    std::smatch match = *i;                                                 
    std::string match_str = s.substr(match.position(1), match.length(1) - 1); //-1 cr
    std::cout << match_str << " =" << match.position(1) << '\n';
}  
}
```

Comment: There aren't any nagative numbers allowed.

Comment: Your are actually looking for overlapping matches? Please edit accordingly.

Comment: Like this: https://regex101.com/r/tbibfe/1

Comment: As you can see in the sample I have posted the result is in group 1.

Comment: wp78de thanks now it works. I must use regex iterator instead of regex search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are actually looking for overlapping matches. This can be achieved using a regex [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
(?=((?:55|66)[0-9a-fA-F]{8,}\/r))
```

You will find the matches in question in group 1. The full-match, however, is empty.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tbibfe/2) <sub>(using `/r` instead of a carriage return for demonstration purposes only)</sub>

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/OTxSkS):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string subject("0055\r06550003665508090705\r0970");
    try {
      std::regex re("(?=((?:55|66)[0-9a-fA-F]{8,}\r))");
      std::sregex_iterator next(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re);
      std::sregex_iterator end;
      while (next != end) {
        std::smatch match = *next;
        std::cout << match.str(1) << "\n";
        next++;
      } 
    } catch (std::regex_error& e) {
      // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See also: [Regex-Info: C++ Regular Expressions with std::regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html)